# How to mock Func<Enum, Interface>() parameter in constructor of the tested class (sut)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constructor, moq, .net-6.0

In my .Net6 web app, I attempted to register service injection for 2 implementations of a single `IWordRepository` Interface:

1. `WordRepositoryInMemory`, working with in-memory data;
2. `WordRepositoryDatabase` with calls to the database;

Following the example set out in [this article](https://medium.com/geekculture/net6-dependency-injection-one-interface-multiple-implementations-983d490e5014), I created an enum:

```cs
public enum WordRepositoryImplementation
{
    WordRepositoryInMemory,
    WordRepositoryDatabase
}
```

Then, in my `Program.cs`, I registered the two services:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<WordRepositoryDatabase>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<WordRepositoryInMemory>();

builder.Services.AddTransient<Func<WordRepositoryImplementation, IWordRepository?>>(wordRepositoryProvider => key =>
{
    return key switch
    {
        WordRepositoryImplementation.WordRepositoryInMemory => wordRepositoryProvider.GetService<WordRepositoryInMemory>(),
        WordRepositoryImplementation.WordRepositoryDatabase => wordRepositoryProvider.GetService<WordRepositoryDatabase>(),
        _ => null,
    };
});
```

Then, I called it in my controller like so:

```cs
private readonly IWordRepository _wordRepositoryDatabase; // I only require one of the implementations to be called by this controller.

public DictionaryDataController(Func<WordRepositoryImplementation, IWordRepository> serviceResolver)
{
    _wordRepositoryDatabase = serviceResolver(WordRepositoryImplementation.WordRepositoryDatabase);
}
```

Unfortunately, this added complexity messed up my tests for the controller. I am no longer able to instantiate the **sut** with a simple **Mock.Object** of the `WordRepositoryDatabase` service. By saying unable, I mean that I don't quite have the required experience handling delegates, yet.

In my test fixture, I tried to replace the original mock implementation of the service:

```cs
private Mock<IWordRepository> _wordRepository;
// ....
_wordRepository= new Mock<IWordRepository>();
// ....
DictionaryDataController sut = new(_wordRepositoryDatabase.Object);
```

To something that returns a Mock of the `IWordRepository`, so that I could use it in my constructor:

```cs
private Func<WordRepositoryImplementation, IWordRepository?> _funcWordRepositoryImplementation;
// ...
// ...
DictionaryDataController sut = new(_funcWordRepositoryImplementation);
```

However, I cannot grasp the required syntax here. The closest I got to was a parameterless Func<>() that returned the Mock.Object, but it was clearly missing something.

```cs
_funcWordRepositoryImplementation= () =>
{
    return new Mock<WordRepositoryImplementation, IWordRepository>();
};
```

And attempts to pass some arguments to it caused their own set of errors.

*What would the correct way to set up this field be?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) with [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards) parameter which will return `_wordRepositoryDatabase.Object`:

```cs
DictionaryDataController sut = new(_ => _wordRepositoryDatabase.Object);
```